# how to copy link name to title

Tags: hyperlink, copy, title

i wanna ask how to change title in

```
<a href="#" title="here">name</a>
```

so i want to make link name copy to title automatic

so if i make this code

```
<a href="#">title link</a>
```

to

```
<a href="#" title="title link">title link</a>
```

how to do that in php or javascript

i know some in php

but need to make all words in link at database or make for every link variable $

can some one help me in that?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest:

```
function textToTitle(elem, attr) {
    if (!elem || !attr) {
        // if function's called without an element/node,
        // or without a string (an attribute such as 'title',
        // 'data-customAttribute', etc...) then returns false and quits
        return false;
    }
    else {
        // if elem is  a node use that node, otherwise assume it's a
        // a string containing the id of an element, search for that element
        // and use that
        elem = elem.nodeType == 1 ? elem : document.getElementById(elem);
        // gets the text of the element (innerText for IE)
        var text = elem.textContent || elem.innerText;
        // sets the attribute
        elem.setAttribute(attr, text);
    }
}

var link = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (var i = 0, len = link.length; i < len; i++) {
    textToTitle(link[i], 'title');
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/HW4SM/).

And since it seems traditional to offer a concise jQuery option:

```
$('a').attr('title', function() { return $(this).text(); });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/HW4SM/6/).

Comment: Put it in `<script></script>` tags before the closing `</body>` tag. It needs to run *after* the DOM is constructed and the elements are available.

Comment: thx is work good

but how to make it for element in html like class or id

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use a library:

```
var allLinks = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var i = 0; i < allLinks.length; i++){
    allLinks[i].title = allLinks[i].innerHTML;
}
```

Since you wanted to do all this to one element on the page, consider using something like this:

```
var allLinks = document.getElementById('myelement').getElementsByTagName('a'); // gets all the link elements out of #myelement
for ( int i = 0; i < allLinks.length; i++ ){
    allLinks[i].title = allLinks[i].innerHTML;
}
```

Actually, this is roughly the same as before but we are changing the input elements.

Or, assuming you use jQuery, you could do something like this:

```
$('a').each(function(){ // runs through each link element on the page
    $(this).attr('title', $(this).html()); // and changes the title to the text within itself ($(this).html())
});
```

Comment: I think `divs.length` in the `for ()` should probably be `allLinks.length`?

Comment: yeah I just changed it, took this out of a project of mine.

Comment: sorry ned it for alot of code in block at html so only this block not all page

Comment: You then just need to edit the first line so it looks like that: `var allLinks = document.getElementById('whatever').getElementsByTagName('a');`. This will take all link elements out of #whatever.

Answer (score 0):

In JQuery you can change an attribute by knowing the current tag and using the .attr() feature. Something like `$('a').attr('title', 'new_title');` http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: this only for all page

how if i want for alot of code in block at html?